# Aplicar MultiThreading(Paralelismo) a mi codigo de Scraping en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hilos

Necesito ayuda para agilizar el proceso de scrape que he hecho. Actualmente hace todo lo que he querido sin aplicar hilos, lo necesito para que mientras se recorre una página obteniendo información, otro proceso siga adelante con otras páginas y así.

Aquí está mi código y el intento de usar Thread.

```
//Primer Proceso (Obtiene el Url de una pagina de productos) 
string FirstUrl = InputTextBox.Text;

//Segundo (Obtiene el documento HTML parsed) 
var doc = GetHtmlDoc(FirstUrl); 

//Obtengo el numero total de paginas que recorrere (ultimo numero de paginacion)
num = GetNumberofPages(doc); 

//Obtengo los urls de cada uno de los productos y Url para ir a la siguiente pagina
Tuple<List<string>, string> myVal = GetAllhrefs(doc); 
string NPage = myVal.Item2; 
LinkProduct = myVal.Item1;

//Comienzo a recorrer
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
  //En vista de ya tener informacion de la primer pagina valido para hacer el scrape
  if (i == 0)
  {
    //Aqui intento hace el thread pero no me arroja resultados (sin el Thread si funciona)
    Thread hiloNuevo = new Thread(() => EnterAllUrl(LinkProduct));
    hiloNuevo.Start();
  }
  else //Segunda vez, segunda pagina, voy y obtengo toda la inforamcion necesaria y aplico lo mismo
  {
    i++;
string newPage = "https://www.testscrape.com" + i;
     var docw = GetHtmlDoc(newPage);
    Tuple<List<string>, string> test = GetAllhrefs(docw);
    string NPage2 = test.Item2;
    LinkProduct = test.Item1;
    //Nuevamente el thread
    Thread hiloNuevo2 = new Thread(() => EnterAllUrl(LinkProduct));
    hiloNuevo2.Start();

    NPage = NPage2;
  }
}


//eSTE METHODO ES EL QUE USO PARA PROCESAR CADA PRODUCTO
private void EnterAllUrl(List<string> LinkProduct)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < LinkProduct.Count; j++)
  {
    string Linking = LinkProduct[j];
    string proxlin = "Linking";
    var DataInfo = GetHtmlDoc(proxlin);
    showData(DataInfo);
  }
}
```

¿Podrían apoyarme con esto? ¿Dónde hay que hacer los cambios para agilizar el proceso?

Comment: ¿Dónde defines "newPage"?

Comment: @fredyfx Es un string donde concateno la url que necesito, ya lo agrego, lo borre sin querer

Comment: @fredyfx editado!

Comment: Que version de .NET estas utilizando? Me gustaria ayudarte.

Comment: @Einer la version es 4.7.02053 con el framework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema se puede resolver más rápido usando `Parallel.foreach` (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop). Es como un `for` estandar pero divide la colección que vas a recorrer en varios procesos.

El único cambio que tienes que hacer es que tiene que ser una colección. Podrías crear un colección con cada página a recorrer y, en tu caso, el código quedaría algo parecido a esto (suponiendo que tienes una colección de `string` llamada `paginas` con las páginas):

```
Parallel.ForEach(pagina, (pagina) => 
{
...
...
...
tu código va aquí
...
...
...
});
```

Espero que te sirva.

Salu2